# How increase UIScrollView height Dynamically with autoLayouts

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Here is my structure of views for this

```
-ViewController
  -UIView
    -UIScrollView
     -UIView * customview
```

Data comes form web Serivce. automatically increase the `UIScrollView` Height and subview Height.
I am fixing autolayouts to `UIScrollView` and `UIView`.
In customview `UILables` and `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the Outlet of your customeview height constrains.

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeight;

bind viewHeight with your customeview height constrains and set the constant property of your outlet

self.viewHeight.constant = 2000; //Your subview Height

in define image you can see the your subview height constrains and bind outlet with this constrains after it height will change dynamically as per your .constant value.

[image]

Comment: Good Job...keep it up..u really saved my day and life....cant explain my feelings...thank you bro.